# MTG Gatherer Regular Expressions whitespace

Tags: magic-the-gathering

How do I represent white space in a phrase on gatherer's advanced search? I read the help, and I've used regexes before, but I can't get this to work for me.

> AND
>   lifelink
>
> NOT
>   m/until\send\sof\turn/
>
> NOT
>   creature

Should give

> AND
>   lifelink
>
> NOT
>   until end of turn
>
> NOT
>   creature

I'm looking for cards that give lifelink as a persistent effect like enchantments or equipment.

What am i doing wrong with the regex? Why does it still show card with end of turn in the text body?

Edit: gatherer specifically instructs to use regex...

http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Help.aspx#regex

Comment: Can you clarify if you're looking for a way to search for a list of cards on Gatherer? If you are, then this is on-topic for the site. If you are writing a regex for use in some program you are writing, then you should just ask this at Stackoverflow.

Comment: Is this about how to work regexes (in Java, maybe with a Gatherer API or something) or is it about using Gatherer's Search page? Seems like the latter, which ought to be within our domain. (Downvotes aren't ban votes, btw, don't know where you got that idea. You're at no risk of getting automatically question banned.) Is there a reason you're not just typing in "until end of turn" (with plain ordinary spaces)?

Comment: An alternative to using the web form to make regex is to put the regex directly into the url.

Comment: You're missing the 's' in between 'of' and 'turn'?

Comment: On their search page

Comment: Because gatherers instructions specifically instruct you to use regex, and spaces break them into seperate searches for ANY instance of each word. I want to search for an exact phrase

Comment: That page says that you can use regular expressions, but that doesn't mean that you should use regular expressions. As I point out in my answer, you don't actually need regular expressions to accomplish what you're trying to do.

Comment: @dopplegreener because stack overflow banned me for having too many downvotes (which have an absolute limit and are not offset by upvotes)

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen Since you're not suspended I presume you mean you're question banned, and the question ban mechanism doesn't work the way you appear to think it works. It requires consistent low quality contributions with regular closures and deletion. You've got enough well-received questions here that downvotes aren't likely to have much effect. (But if you do consistently provide low quality material that earns downvotes, we're not interested in saving you from the question ban it'd incur.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are representing whitespace properly. "\s" is a placeholder for "one whitespace character," but your search doesn't yield the expected results because, as has been stated before, gatherer doesn't properly negate regex search terms.

You can use a Negative Lookahead group combined with a single wildcard, repeated together, in order to check to make sure the specified phrase doesn't appear anywhere in the field. The regex for "cards that do not contain the text 'Until end of turn'" would be m/^((?!Until\send\sof\sturn).)*$/

The specific gatherer url for your query would be:
[http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[lifelink]+[m/^((?!Until\send\sof\sturn).)*$/]&type=+![%22Creature%22]](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&text=+[lifelink]+[m/%5E((?!Until%5Csend%5Csof%5Csturn).)*$/]&type=+![%22Creature%22])

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the Gatherer search simply does not understand negated regular expressions. I tried, and it gives the exact same results with `NOT <regular expression>` as with `AND <regular expression>`.

Fortunately, your search does not require the use of regular expressions at all. You can find what you're looking for just by using `NOT "until end of turn"` instead.

Comment: You solved my problem, but i feel reluctant to accept it since it does not answer the question itself. Regex is powerful, and it would be amazing to be able to use it on gatherers search page. If it proves that it will not parse regex, you would have been the first to suggest it and i would accept. But a solution is not the purpose here.  The WWW needs answers. =P

Comment: This does answer your question. You ask why your query isn't giving the results you expect. The answer is that Gatherer does not properly handle negated regular expressions. That doesn't mean that regular expressions don't work at all.